# Inner Join 2 tables and count occurrences of foreign key in each

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using Mysql and I have 3 tables,

**banners** (id,type,page)

**clicks** (id,banner_id)

**impressions** (id,banner_id)

Where **banner_id** is the foreign key in **clicks** and **impressions** tables. I need to produce rows like this

**Required Result Table**

```
id, type, clicks_count, impressions_count
```

Perfomance-wise, what is the best mysql query to use to achieve the result above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `JOIN` the three tables, use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select id, type, count(c.id) clicks_count, count(i.id) as impressions_count
from banners b
  left join clicks c on b.id = c.banner_id
  left join impressions i on b.id = i.banner_id
group by id, type
```

Or use correlated sub-queries to count:

```
select id, type,
       (select count(*) from clicks c where b.id = c.banner_id) clicks_count,
       (select count(*) from impressions i where b.id = i.banner_id) impressions_count
from banners b
```

Comment: But how does it count the clicks? is it not suppose to have a count somewhere?